# How to Update an Owned Type on EF Core

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.0

I have these classes

```
public class ProcessExecution : AggregateRoot
{
    public Guid ParticipantId { get; protected set; }

    public Guid ProcessId { get; protected set; }

    public Process.Process Process { get; protected set; }

    public ICollection<ArtifactExecution> Executions { get; protected set; }
}

public class ArtifactExecution : Entity<Guid>
{
    public ProcessArtifact Artifact { get; set; }
    public Guid ArtifactId { get; set; }

    public Guid ExecutionId { get; protected set; }
    public ProcessExecution Execution { get; protected set; }

    public ArtifactExecutionStatus ExecutionStatus { get; protected set; }
}

public class ArtifactExecutionStatus : ValueObject<ArtifactExecutionStatus>
{
    public string Status { get; protected set; }

    protected ArtifactExecutionStatus()
    {

    }

    public ArtifactExecutionStatus(string status)
    {
        Status = status;
    }
}
```

and here is the ef mappings

```
class ProcessExecutionMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Workflow.Domain.Execution.ProcessExecution>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Workflow.Domain.Execution.ProcessExecution> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

        builder.Property(x => x.ParticipantId)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.HasOne(x => x.Process)
            .WithMany(x => x.Executions)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ProcessId);

        builder.HasMany(x => x.Executions)
            .WithOne(x => x.Execution)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ExecutionId);

        builder.Ignore(x => x.Events);
    }
}

class ArtifactExecutionMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ArtifactExecution>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ArtifactExecution> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

        builder.HasOne(x => x.Execution)
            .WithMany(x => x.Executions)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ExecutionId);

        builder.HasOne(x => x.Artifact)
            .WithMany(x => x.Executions)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ArtifactId);

        builder.OwnsOne(x => x.ExecutionStatus, ob =>
        {
            ob.ToTable(nameof(ArtifactExecution));
            ob.Property(x => x.Status)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName("Status")
                .HasColumnType("varchar(50)");
        });
    }
}
```

The goal here is to use some DDD aproach using value objects.
When I need to save the aggregate, it's all ok.

Now, in my model, sometimes I need to execute something like this.

`ExecutionStatus = new ArtifactExecutionStatus("FINISHED");`

When I need to update, I get this exception.

> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request
>   System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type
>   'ArtifactExecution.ExecutionStatus#ArtifactExecutionStatus' cannot be
>   tracked because another instance with the key value
>   'ArtifactExecutionId:e1330424-a41f-4332-9d98-1c432d3367f8' is already
>   being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one
>   entity instance with a given key value is attached.

When updating, I'm using the native `DbSet.Update(entity)` of ef-core, so, all cascades should be working.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: it sounds like your create 2 of the same entity and EF doesn't know which to save because both are being tracked in memory.  Are you attaching entities to your context some where before verifying the Id's are unique?

Comment: I need to create one more, because it's a value object, so I replace the instance for another.

Comment: EF (Core) uses reference equality to track entity instances (including the owned types). So forget about value objects and DDD/OOP things and use simple mutable classes as expected by EF. EF entity model never been and still isn't "domain" model, but "store" model with its own requirements.